# Background image and window size

Tags: css, background, resize, window, size

I have a bg image set to the body of my website and when viewed in full screen/window, the bg acts as it should.  However, if I make the window smaller, the bg image acts odd/wrong.  I tried to read up on it however it's easier to show than to explain and I'm not entirely sure what to call it.  It's a wp site and my own custom template, however I am new to development in general.

http://villagesilversmith.javiercortez.com/

Comment: Can you give us as to what looks 'wrong'? I'm really not sure what I'm supposed to be looking for here.

Comment: resize the window to get a width of under 960px. You'll see a horizontal scrollbar showing up. Scroll to the right, and there you have it. Moreover, the background image is expected to be centered related to the logo and everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background image is set up correctly. The problem is that when you down size the width of the page below the width of your content, some weird behavior occur. Add `min-width: 960px;` style to your .page element to prevent this problem.